# How to repair working copy after `git pull` failed due to disk space

Tags: git

I tried to `git pull` and ran out of disk space while it was performing the operation. Now there are a bunch of untracked files, and tracked files that git claims have been modified, sprinkled throughout my working copy.

There are also untracked and modified files in the working copy that I would like to keep (yes, I know I should have `git commit` before trying to pull).

Is there any command that will make git undo *only* the operations that it performed during the aborted pull attempt? I know I can do
`git reset --hard HEAD` and `git clean -f` as a last resort but I would like to keep my local changes if possible.

Comment: I know it's too late now, but still: This is a good example of why you should try to have a clean working copy before performing any git operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in a merge state you could look at `git merge --abort`, or otherwise perhaps  `git reset --merge` but do read the man pages to avoid shooting yourself in the foot.

A safer but maybe tedious option is to create a new branch and commit your current state to it, and then merge or cherry-pick from that branch. If you want to cherry-pick, you may organize your current changes in multiple commits to facilitate that (e.i., commit *your* uncommitted changes separately in a meaningful set of commits).
A similar option is to stash your working dir before you reset and redo the pull.